# Как плавно скрыть элемент при помощи значения visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня появилась такая проблема когда проходит время выполняется функции с этим проблем нет. Но когда я скрываю элемент при помощи значения visibility: hidden; происходит резкая анимация исчезновения. А мне нужно чтобы это было плавно. Помоги пожалуйста. Если вопрос показался тупым то извините.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function hide(){
  document.querySelector('.block').classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
  .block{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background:red;
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all .2s linear;
  }
  
  .hide{
    opacity:0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .2s linear;
  }
```

```html
<div onclick = 'hide()' class = 'block'>
</div>

<button onclick = 'hide()' > hide </button>
```

Comment: Это правда. Для подобных переходов используется свойство `transition` со следующей сигнатурой: `<на_что_реагировать> <длительность_перехода> <тип_перехода>`. [Подробнее в документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: Это враньё. `visibility` тут никакой роли не играет, плавное скрытые происходит с помощью свойства `opacity` которое со значения `1` переходит в значение `0`. Можно было бы и написать что плавное скрытие происходит с помощью `opacity`.

Comment: иногда бывают моменты когда нужно и visibility и opacity, например когда нужно плавно скрыть блок и не взаимодействовать с ним, display: none тут не поможет, анимации с ним не сработают, поэтому тут используется visibility  и opacity.